# How to best abstract class variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I've got a class such as

```
# this has been simplified for the example
class MyClass
  @@private_attributes = []

  def self.private_attributes(*args)
    @@private_attributes = args
  end

  def private_attributes
    @private_attributes ||= @@private_attributes
  end
end
```

It works great. I've this `@@private_attributes` set at class level which's then used at instance level in multiple ways.

I want to abstract this logic somewhere else to simplify my class, something like that

```
class MyClass
  include PrivateAttributes
end
```

When I create the module `PrivateAttributes`, however I shape it, the `@@private_attributes` isn't understood at `MyClass` level.

I tried many things but here's the latest code attempt

```
module PrivateAttributes
  include ProcessAttributes

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
    base.include(InstanceMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    @@private_attributes = []

    def private_attributes(*args)
      @@private_attributes = args
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def private_attributes
      @private_attributes ||= process_attributes_from(@@private_attributes)
    end

    def private_attributes?
      instance_options[:scope] == :private
    end
  end
end
```

It crashes with this error

```
 NameError:
   uninitialized class variable @@private_attributes in PrivateAttributes::InstanceMethods
   Did you mean?  private_constant
```

In short, the `@@private_attributes` isn't transferred throughout the code, but looks like it stays at the module level.

What's the best way to abstract this logic from my original class ?

Comment: When you moved the `@@private_attributes` to the module it is now module variable and not a class variable. One way to get around is that you use `mattr_accessor :private_attributes` inside `ClassMethods` module and use the getter for `private_attributes` in `process_attributes_from` like so: `process_attributes_from(self.class.private_attributes)`

Comment: Note that when you use PrivateAttributes module inside some other class and set private_attributes, changes will reflect in your MyClass as well.

Comment: It seems to work great, thanks for the input, the `mattr_accessor` is a perfect workaround I didn't think of !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working solution**

An easy workaround is to use `mattr_accessor` on the class level or anything similar to communicate our data around. I preferred to write down my own methods in this case:

```
module PrivateAttributes
  include ProcessAttributes

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
    base.include(InstanceMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    @@private_attributes_memory = []

    def private_attributes(*args)
      @@private_attributes_memory = args
    end

    def private_attributes_memory
      @@private_attributes_memory
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def private_attributes
      @private_attributes ||= process_attributes_from private_attributes_memory
    end

    # you can add diverse methods here
    # which will be used in MyClass once included

    private

    def private_attributes_memory
      self.class.private_attributes_memory
    end
  end
end
```